# How do I load contents of a file into an environment variable in dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have constraints listed in a requirements file for a python installation, I'm quite new to docker so I'm not sure if this scenario is recommended :

- Copy `custom-constraints-3.6.txt` to container
- Use ENV to store the contents of this file in a variable `PYTHON_DEPS` (How would I do this?)
- use variable, e.g. `RUN pip install apache-airflow[gcp]==1.10.12 --constraint ${PYTHON_DEPS}`

How can I copy and use the above-mentioned constraints in my dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want the contents of the file to be stored in an environment variable? From my reading, the `--constraint` option expects to receive a file path.

Assuming you're going to pass the file path as the `--constraint` option, then you could use something like the following:

```
FROM image

# Copy the constraints-3.6.txt file into the container
COPY custom-constraints-3.6.txt .

# Use the constraints file which was copied by the previous instruction into the container
RUN pip install apache-airflow[gcp]==1.10.12 --constraint custom-constraints-3.6.txt
```

If you want to read the file's contents into an environment variable, maybe try something like.

```
FROM image

# Copy the constraints-3.6.txt file into the container
COPY custom-constraints-3.6.txt .

# Set the PYTHON_DEPS environment variable to the contents of the file
RUN export PYTHON_DEPS="$(cat custom-constraints-3.6.txt)"
```

EDIT: It looks like the second option, passing the --constraint option anything other than a file path, isn't a viable way to pass the constraints to pip. So only the first method is correct.

Comment: Thank you ! The first method worked, but I'm curious how to make the second work aswell. I seem to be doing something wrong with `RUN pip install apache-airflow[gcp]==1.10.12 --constraint ${PYTHON_DEPS}` because I keep getting `[8/8] RUN pip install apache-airflow[gcp]==1.10.12 --constraint "${PYTHON_DEPS}": [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''`. I also tried with `{PYTHON_DEPS}` (Without double-quotes). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like the second option, passing the `--constraint` option anything other than a file path, isn't a viable way to pass the constraints to pip.

Comment: Thank you :) although it's not clear to me why it's trying to find `''` instead of a list of python dependencies loaded from the file.